# Chrome Pixelated on 4k Monitor

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, 4k-resolution

I have a Windows 10 PC and connect to a 4k monitor via display port cable.
All native app seems to be very clear, except **Chrome**.

I noticed the blur on tabs, favicons and texts.

Is there a tool/package to prevent that ?

Comment: chrome looks fine for me on UHD. I do run canary though

Answer (score 0):

Try doing what [this](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/chrome-high-dpi-mode/) article says.

It's a registry edit to enable high DPI support for Chrome.

Search for regedit in the Windows 10 search feature, then navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome`.  Look for a key called `Profile`.  If there isn't one, make one by right clicking on Chrome in the editor, then add new key.  Call it `Profile`.  Click on the existing or new `Profile` key then right click on the pane in the editor and select `New > DWORD (32-bit) Value` and name the new DWORD `high-dpi-support`.  Double click on the new DWORD and enter the value 1 and press OK.  Close regedit, and close Chrome if it's open (you may have to kill all tasks and processes for it in Task Manager), and open Chrome back up.